Tailwind style not applying in Yarn Monorepo re-usable common components
So we trying to integrate tailwind in our existing Yarn Monorepo structure. It's fine with the apps (works as expected), but got stuck with figuring out how re-usable components from @common can get tailwind css applied. IDE detects tailwind. This is our structure. Would love to get some help, I know it's simple solution, but didn't found any examples:
Structure:
.
├── app-admin                 
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── App.tsx
│   │   └── index.tsx
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── postcss.config.cjs      #importing config from @common/config
│   ├── tailwind.config.mjs     #importing config from @common/config
│   └── vite.config.mts
│
├── app-main              
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── App.tsx
│   │   └── index.tsx
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── postcss.config.cjs      #importing config from @common/config
│   ├── tailwind.config.mjs     #importing config from @common/config
│   └── vite.config.mts
│
└── common                    
    ├── components/         
    │   └── HelloWorld/
    │       └── index.tsx              #this is the problem
    ├── config/               
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── postcss.config.cjs
    │   ├── style.css
    │   ├── tailwind.config.mjs
    │   └── vite.config.mts
    ├── index.ts              
    ├── package.json
    └── tsconfig.json

HelloWorld.tsx
import '@common/config/style.css';

export const HelloWorld = () => <h1 className="p-3 text-green-600">Hello</h1>;

Current App.tsx example from @app-main (testing)
import { HelloWorld } from '@common/components';

const App: FC = () => (
  <>
    <h1 className="">
      <HelloWorld />
    </h1>
    <p className="text-red-600">this is some text</p>
    <p className="p-4">this is some text</p>
  </>
);

export default App;

Visual example. Text "Hello" from @common/components expected to have p-3 text-green-600:

